# Directory Searcher SearchResultCollection.count is very slow

Tags: vb.net, directoryservices

I have a directory searcher that is looking for dynamic groups.
When I try to process the results it is taking 30 seconds to return the results.
the ds.findall is very fast but when I try to find out the number of records returned
or anything about the results it take the 30 seconds. So i am assuming that this is where the actual retreival of information is taking place.  Why does it take so long and is there a way to speed it up. Code is below.

```
query = "(&(objectClass=dynamicgroup)(member=cn=mvander,ou=reg,ou=Employees,ou=staff,o=wpsr))"

Dim results As SearchResultCollection
Dim result As SearchResult
entry = GetValidDirectoryEntry(searchRootAdsPath, True)

ds = New DirectorySearcher(entry)
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attributesToQuery("GroupMembership"))
results = ds.FindAll
'This line takes up to 30 seconds to return the results
If results.Count > 0 Then
'I have a for each loop that processes the results
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it absolutely necessary to check the count before entering the loop?  Can't you just check to make sure that results is not null, then iterate over whatever *is* there?  (Since you say that you have a processing 'For' loop following the Count check anyway; why enumerate the connection an extra time to get the count?)

Comment: I found out that the problem was the dynamic groups. It had to expand all of the users in the dynamic groups to see if the user I was looking for was in it. As we added memeber and more dynamic groups this got unmanagable.